# Replace SWF file with image for mobile devices

Tags: php, mobile, flash, slideshow

i have built a website www.jetcleandrives.co.uk However, i have noticed that the SWF file does not display on mobile devices. Can anyone advise me of the best way round this. For example can PHP be used to display an image instead on devices that can't handle SWF? Or is there a way to display the slideshow on all devices?

The code for the slideshow is,

```
<div id="Slideshow">
  <object width="450" height="338" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="https://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" title="Slideshow of Driveway Cleaning Selly Oak"> 
    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="" />
    <param name="movie" value="media/JetCleanDrivesSlideshow.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <embed width="450" height="338" scale="showall" wmode="transparent" quality="high" src="media/JetCleanDrivesSlideshow.swf" pluginspage="https://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
  </object>

  </div><!--end Slideshow-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider switching from using the `object` tag to SWFObject (http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) for a bit more control/flexibility.

There is a simple example available on the project's documentation page: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0");
</script>
```

And then you can specify alternative content:

```
<div id="myContent">
  <p>Alternative content</p>
</div>
```

I think this would be enough for your requirements.

**Additional:** One of the (more advanced) features I like about SWFObject is the ability to register a JavaScript function as a callback, which is fired once SWFObject has loaded. The developer can then check the status of SWFObject and unhide/replace content.

An example of this can be found at: http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/testsuite_2_2/test2.html